# Openvino with python is returning some error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openvino

I'm trying to run [this](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_demos_python_demos_face_recognition_demo_README.html) application using openvino, but I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.7 of module 'openvino.inference_engine.ie_api' does not match runtime version 3.6
>     return f(*args, **kwds)

But when I ran the application using python 3.7, I've got this error:

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./face_recognition_demo.py", line 24, in 
>       import cv2
>   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that some packages in your environment are incompatible. To fix this I recommend to run the sample using virtual environment. Please follow:

```
python3 -m venv ./virtual-env
source ./virtual-env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Then try to run the sample again.